# Robot Framework not clicking dropdown menu in firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework

I've been trying to navigate through a webpage and testing the different links using Robot and Selenium.
I need to click several Dropdown menus. In Google chrome it works fine, but when I use Firefox there will always be one dropdown menu (not always the same one) that will appear selected (Like when a mouse passes over a button), but it will not get clicked.

The code I've been using:

```
 Wait Until Element Is Visible  //*[@id="Modules"]/a           timeout=20s
 Click Element                  //*[@id="Modules"]/a
 Wait Until Element Is Visible  xpath: //*[contains(text(), "Tasklist")]          timeout=20s
 Click Element                  xpath: //*[contains(text(), "Tasklist")]
```

This is the element HTML code:

```
<li id="Modules" class="nav-item nav-item-levels mega-menu-full show">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-nav-link dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-modx"></i>
    <span class="menu-item-name" style="color: inherit; display: none;">Modules</span></a>
```

And this is the screen I'm trying to click on (In my test case, the "modules" dropdown menu appears selected, but the menu doesn't drop down)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC3Yb.png)

So far I've tried increasing selenium_speed and adding a  `sleep` command before clicking, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone knows what the problem with Firefox could be?

Comment: can you add any html to your question?

Comment: try 
Double click element